# Where should we unsubscribe from Angular's SwUpdate.available?

Tags: angular

In a video by Angular' member, Stephen, he demonstrated ["Updates and Notifications with the Angular Service Worker"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eoaE0M_DRFI).

Where and when should we unsubscribe from Angular's SwUpdate.available? Or should we even be concerned with the overhead from this subscribe, even if it is not unsubscribed?

Stephen subscribed to this code snipped below.

```js
  constructor(update: SwUpdate, push: SwPush, snackbar: MatSnackBar) {
    update.available.subscribe(update => {
      console.log('update available');
    });
}
```

Comment: Subscribing to `SwUpdate` means you care about updated info of your contents. Normally you will need it while your app is running. So you don't need to unsubscribe from it  or just unsubscribe when you don't care about it any more for some specific reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use takeWhile and check that service worker update is enabled. As long as it is enabled we continue subscription.

`constructor(update: SwUpdate, push: SwPush) {
    update.available
      .pipe(
        takeWhile(() => this.swUpdate.isEnabled)
      )
      .subscribe(update => {
        console.log('update available');
      });
  }`

Comment: When there is an update, it will not automatically detecting the changes, unless you do a "refresh/reload".

Answer (score 2):

Do not listen to Pengyy. You should unsubscribe from all Subscribtions if there is a possibility that those subscribtions might accumulate (and thus produce a memory leak).

What I mean by that is that if the subscribtion is not in a global service or utility-class that gets called only once, but in a Component (which gets initialized and destroyed as the user clicks through the app), then you should do something like:

```
private _destroy$ = new Subject();

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this._destroy$.next();
}

constructor(private _store: Store<AppState>) {
  this._store.select(someReduxStream$).takeUntil(this._destroy$).subscribe(value => {/**/});
}
```

If you don't want to add this code to every component with streams in your app yourself, you can use an Aspect/Decorator like: https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-take-until-destroy

If you have a stream somewhere that you know you will use only one single time, then you can unsubscribe from it after receiving the first value:

```
stream$.take(1).subscribe(value => {/**/});
```

Comment: Note that all RXJS methods that start with `take` are meant for unsubscribing, but the two I mentioned are the ones I use 99% of the times